# how to produce a 48-bit number on a 32-bit system

Tags: 32bit-64bit, unix-timestamp

The task is to send out to the network the little-endian bytes that represent the number of miliseconds since the UNIX epoch --- using a 32-bit system.

The number 1510747673476 represents the current date, 2017 november 15th.  In a 32-bit system, the system can't think of this number.  It also doesn't have a source of miliseconds since the UNIX epoch.  But it does have a source of the number of seconds.  It is acceptable that we produce 48-bit numbers whose miliseconds are always zero.

Say y = 1510747673 is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch of the current date.  Is there a way to format 1510747673 * 10^3 instead?  Meaning I'd get the bytes for the number 1510747673 and somehow discover which other two bytes I need to compose the little endian bytes of 1510747673 * 10^3?  That's the question.

Feel free to ask a better question.  The objective is to deliver the 6 bytes of the current date in miliseconds.  The receiving end expects it in little-endian and with a 48-bit size.

Comment: What programming language are you talking about here?

Comment: We're talking about Lua.  Is it relevant?

Comment: "32-bit" is just the word size. It is not a limitation of the computer.

Comment: Generally yes - programming languages generally abstract away the problem of dealing with types larger than the native size of the hardware.  I'm not familiar with Lua, but I imagine it has some way to deal with "large" integer types.

Comment: I see.  I have a library available that formats 32-bit integers.  I'm discovering I can handle larger numbers.  It seems this Lua system uses double datatypes for integers.  For example, setting y = 1510747673476 and printing it out gives 1.51075e+12.  I'm not sure if this is just the printing or whether it really lost the part "673476" of the number.  But goins that route is totally unknown territory for me.  So I've been formatting numbers up to 32 bits with the library I have --- which always gives me 4 bytes for any number it formats.

Answer (score 0):

You have the number of seconds y, which fits into a 32-bit datatype.  You want to format y + 10^3 in little-endian.  So you need the two little-endian bytes that represent 10^3.  These are 0xe8 and 0x03.

So take your library that formats 32-bit integers and get the 4 bytes that represents y.  These will be the 4 most significant bytes of your 48-bit integer.  Call them b3, b4, b5, b6.  The desired little-endian answer is 0xe8, 0x03, b3, b4, b5, b6.

Comment: This isn't correct at all.  I'll try to find a different way, but this is totally wrong.  If you can, delete this answer completely.